# How do I get all the variables that are in a module, but excluding the variables that are imported in that module

Tags: python, python-2.7

So here's the scene. I have a module as:

Filename A:

```
import a_local_module

item = [ 1, 2, 3]
```

Filename B:

```
import A

list_of_variables = dir(A)
```

The thing here is that now there is a list of variables from `A` and `a_local_module`. But I want to get the list of variables declared in file `A` and not from its import of `a_local_module`.

Also assuming that I don't know what the imports in file A are.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can ignore the variables if they have the type `module`, but this will only work with `import a_local_module` and not `from a_local_module import thing`.

Comment: What if `A` did `from a_local_module import function; function = patch(function)`?

Comment: @Alex, what is type `module`? When I list the type of all variables in `list_of_variables` all I get is `str`.

Comment: @Alex, I don't want to parse `A.py` and can't modify anything in it.

Comment: Yes because those are just the names of the variables. `vars(A)` will give you a dictionary with the actual values.

Answer (score 2):

Just import `a_local_module` yourself and compare:

```
import a_local_module as local
import A

variables = [k
    for k, v in vars(A).iteritems()
        if getatrr(local, k, object()) is v]
```

Comment: I can't do that because I may not know what modules are imported in that file. All I know is that there is a file called `A` and I need the variables declared only in that file.

Comment: Last line can be shortened to `if getattr(local, k, object()) is v`.

Comment: @shift-esc I'm on mobile, so I can't test, but I think every object has a `__module__` attribute that gives you the name of the file in which it was created.  If that is the case, the solution is similar to what I have.  If you can confirm that, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @zondo I think it's just functions and classes that have that.

Comment: @Alex: I was afraid that would be the case.